# Jar file cannot find SWT library, but Eclipse can

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ant

I have an `Ant` build (see `build.xml` below) that compiles and runs as I expect within `Eclipse`.

When I run the build via the command-line (`java -jar swtgui.jar`), however, I receive the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Layout
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        ...
        etc
```

**build.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <project default="run" name="My Project ">

 <target name="run" depends="createjar">
  <java classname="com.company.program.project.MyMainClass">
    <classpath path="staging">
      <fileset dir="C:\COMPANY\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins">
        <include name="org.eclipse.swt.*.jar" />
      </fileset>
    </classpath>
   </java>
  </target>

 <target name="createjar" depends="compile">
  <jar destfile="./builds/jars/swtgui.jar" basedir="staging" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
      <manifest>
         <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.company.program.project.MyMainClass" />
      </manifest>

    <fileset dir="C:\COMPANY\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\"     includes="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.6.0.v3650b.jar" />
  </jar>
 </target>

<target name="compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging">
       <classpath>
            <fileset dir="C:\COMPANY\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins">
              <include name="org.eclipse.swt.*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

</target>

<record name="./MyMainClass.log" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
```

The error doesn't make sense to me since I specify the same SWT library path for the `compile` target as I do for the `createjar` target.

If the SWT library is found for the `compile` target, why is it not found for the `createjar` target?